# NSDate being interpreted several hours off (minutes and day working fine)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am updating the question to be more precise, thank you for the feedback already.

So I am setting a cell for a tableview and displaying the time of the event on the cell itself and to do so am using Parse. The date is downloading correctly from parse as evidenced by the first println, but when I make the label text equal the dateToString of the when date (which is the one from parse) it throws it off by several hours for some reason. The simulator however displays the right time on the status bar and the phones gps is set to EST as well... So I am very confused.

Here is the entire function:

```
func configureCell(object : PFObject)-> Void {

    eventNameText.text = (object.objectForKey("name") as? String)!
    var when = (object.objectForKey("when") as? NSDate)!
    numEchoesText.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: object.objectForKey("numEchoes")!)

    println(when)

    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat =  "EEEE, h:mm a"

    parseid = object.objectId!

    if (contains(echoes, parseid)) {
        echoImage.setImage(imageEchoed, forState: .Normal)
    }

    else {
        echoImage.setImage(imageUnechoed, forState: .Normal)
    }
    var now = NSDate()


    whenText.text = formatter.stringFromDate(when)
    println(formatter.stringFromDate(now))
    println(formatter.stringFromDate(when))
    self.object = object
}
```

And here is the result:

```
2015-05-31 23:43:00 +0000
Tuesday, 9:30 AM
Sunday, 7:43 PM
```

Please note that the first time is correct but the datetostring is interpreting it as the third line. I added a middle println to display the current date in order to show that the datetostring is working correctly for the now date.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and explain what you are getting and what you actually want.

Comment: What does "**throwing off** the date to string method of nsdateformatter" mean?

Comment: Hi I updated my question to try to better clarify what I was after. The reason I intitially asked how to truncate NSDate objects was that I figured it would solve my problem but I no longer believe that to be the case after trying the NSCalendar components solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** updated answer based on new details.

Your trouble is because of the timezone. `NSDate` does not store any time zone information.

```
println(when)
--> 2015-05-31 23:43:00 +0000   // notice the timezone is 0000 / GMT
```

Adding a timezone to the `NSDateFormatter` will help you see what's going on behind the scene:

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat =  "EEEE, h:mm a z"
println(formatter.stringFromDate(when))
--> Sunday, 7:43 PM xyz    // Depends on the timezone on your device
```

The two represents the same point in time, but expressed in different timezones. To solve this, you need to set the timezone of the formatter to GMT:

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, h:mm a z"
formatter.timeZone   = NSTimeZone.init(name:"GMT")
println(formatter.stringFromDate(when))
--> Sunday, 11:43 PM GMT
```

You can remove the timezone identifier now that you get it correct. Date & time manipulation in Cocoa / iOS are a lot more complicated than other languages (Java, C#, Javascript, etc.) Sometimes I wish Apple just created a `NSDate` class with methods to add & subtract date/time components, switch timezone, etc. I can dream on.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, it worked to create a new date object with seconds set to zero but unfortunately I realized that it didn't solve my actual problem. I updated my question to better reflect it. I apologize for the poor phrasing of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NSDateFormatter and how it works. If I do understand your question clearly, I think this should work.

```
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
    dateFormatter.stringFromDate(parseDateObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

`2015-05-31 23:43:00 +0000` means "the 31st of May 2015 at 23:43:00 at +0000 from UTC".

According to your question "The simulator however displays the right time on the status bar and the phones gps is set to EST".

If you convert that date from UTC to EST you get "Sunday, 7:43 PM".

**Your `NSDate` is therefore being interpreted perfectly.**

Making reasonable assumptions about the Parse API, it looks like somebody has imported your data incorrectly.

Comment: Wow something this simple... Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to get the user's timezone when they use a datepicker object so that I can make a new date to submit to parse that is adjusted to UTC and then can be reinterpreted back into timezones when users view it in a cell?

Comment: You can get the local timezone with `let timezone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()`

Comment: `UIDatePicker` should be returning dates adapted per the system's timezone*; are you sure something strange isn't happening between you and Parse. (* they'll still `println` in UTC; what a date is and how a date is printed are separate issues — in Apple's terminology a date is the identifier for a moment in time, which was experienced by everyone in the world simultaneously regardless of what the numbers on their wall clocks were displaying)